# Make field insertable but not updatable in Spring Data REST + MongoDB

Tags: jackson, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

With Spring Data REST and Spring Data Mongo, I want to make a domain field (field `username` of domain `User` in my example) **insertable** when create but **un-updatable** when update. In other words an equivalent of JPA @Column(insertable = true, updatable = false).

I try a few approach but not work.
In my [github project](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-data-rest-mongo-field-non-updatable), domain class and repository are put in /src/main/java/*/*/User.java and UserRepository.java. The test is put in /src/test/java/*/*UserTest.java.

### 1. Spring Data annotation @ReadOnlyProperty and @Transient

The field is un-insertable when save to DB. See package `readonlyproperty` and `transient_` in the project.

### 2. Jackson annotation @JsonProperty(access=READ_ONLY)

The field is un-insertable when create via POST request, because the JSON property is ignored when initiate an object. See package `jsonpropertyreadonly` in the project.

### 3. @JsonCreator on constructor and @JsonIgnore on setter

If the un-updatable field `username` is contained in json body of PUT or PATCH request, and `username` value changes, `username` get updated, which is unexpected. See package `jsoncreator` in the project.

### 4. Do not write a setter

same as 3. See package `nosetter` in the project.

### 5. Toggle on/off feature

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-ignored-properties=false
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=false
spring.jackson.mapper.infer-property-mutators=false
```

not help

### Spring Data REST PUT and PATCH Internal Implementation

- PUT: it uses Jackson `ObjectMapper.readerFor(Class)` to initiate a new object
- PATCH: it uses Jackson `ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating(objectToUpdate).readValue(json)`, which use setter to update the `objectToUpdate`. Seems `readerForUpdating` doesn't see the @JsonIgnore on setter.

The only solution I know is implementing the setter in below way

```java
void setUsername(String usernameToSet) {
    if (null == this.username)
        this.username = usernameToSet;
}
```

And disable PUT method, only use PATCH to update. See package `setterchecknull`.

Is there a better way? Thank you very much!!

Comment: There is a Jackson github [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1401) about ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating(value) to handle ignored property since 2016 but not implemented yet. I'd better wait for the impl and use the setter null check for now.

Comment: I submit an [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2514) to Spring Data MongoDB Team to ask whether it's possible to add an annotation which makes a field read-only, the result is not likely.

Comment: is this still unsolved?

Comment: @Joergi Not resolved yet. Currently I check null in setter.